# PHP - Lumen: update retorna true mas não atualiza os dados na base

Tags: php, mysql, lumen

sou iniciante em PHP - Lumen e estou fazendo minha primeira api. Todos os meus métodos no controller estão funcionando, exceto o update. Mesmo ele retornando true, os dados não são alterados na base.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $agendamento = $this->model->find($id)
        ->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($agendamento);
}
```

Já verifiquei e o $request está trazendo os dados corretamente.

Comment: Existe alguma alteração para ser feita? Como está seu objeto antes e depois de enviar a request? Como estão os dados da requisição?

Comment: 1 -  GET/2
`{
    "Id": 2,
    "IdSala": 2,
    "EmailRequisitante": "teste@email.com",
    "DataHoraInicio": "2019-12-06 15:00:00",
    "DataHoraFim": "2019-12-06 16:00:00",
    "Situacao": "Avitva",
    "Descricao": "Teste data e hora"
}`

2 - PUT/2
`{
 "Id": 2,   
 "IdSala": 2,
 "EmailRequisitante": "teste@email.com",
 "DataHoraInicio": "2019-12-06 15:00:00",
 "DataHoraFim": "2019-12-06 16:30:35",
 "Situacao": "Avitva",
 "Descricao": "Teste data e hora  MODIFICADO"
}`

Após o PUT, ao fazer um novo GET, os dados retornados permanecem como na primeira situação.

Comment: Meu mapeamento `$router->put("/{id}", "AgendamentoController@update");`

Answer (score 0):

Ana, eu não tenho experiencia no Lumen mas no seu pai Laravel eu trato os dados antes de salvar ou atualizar, nunca chamo  o $request dentro do update mas antes mapeio os dados;

```
 $stockTeam = new StockTeam();
                $stockTeam->idTeam = $request->idTeam;
                $stockTeam->idSupplies = $request->idSupplies;
                $stockTeam->amount = $request->amount;
                $stockTeam->save();
```

Espero ter ajudado, essa é a forma que eu já trabalhei com Laravel já fiz isso também:

```
 DB::insert('insert into address_transfers
    ( name, type_id, plan_id, neighborhood_id, status_id, dot, user_id, description, created_at, updated_at)
        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, current_timestamp, ?)',
     [ $request->name, $request->type, $request->plans, $request->hood, $request->status, $request->dot, Auth::id(), $request->description, $request->date ]);
```

Comment: eu tentei mapear os dados do request e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Eu passei boa parte do dia lendo isso. Descobri que o lumen "engana" as requisições PUT e PATCH e na hora de chamar no postman é preciso colocar os parâmetros em 'x-www-url-formurlencoded'. Mas não sei bem como seria a sintaxe para colocar todo o objeto que está sendo mandando dentro do request.

Comment: Ana vê se esses dois links podem te ajudar.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data

https://dev.to/sidthesloth92/understanding-html-form-encoding-url-encoded-and-multipart-forms-3lpa

Comment: o que resolveu pra mim foi colocar os nomes dos parametros do model todos em minusculo

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu.